# Refactor messy subscribing in order to further subscribe

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I am learning Angular and have come across Observables which I like and still don't fully understand. So I have an Observable that needs the completion of an observable in order to proceed.

I had some sequence issues because they are independent, so I needed to nest them to ensure the second Observable waits for the completion of the first one.
I wondered if there is a better approach to what I have done as it seems well a bit of a mess. I will probably need to add another nested observable to this structure.

Here is an example of my code...

```
    this.permissionService.build().subscribe( p =>{
        this.Headers = p; 
        this.accessService.buildTitlesWithMenus().subscribe( q => {
          this.treeNodes = this.accessService.buildTreeTable(q); 
        });                 
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.permissionService.build().pipe(
  tap(p => this.Headers = p),
  switchMap(p => this.accessService.buildTitlesWithMenus()),
).subscribe(q => this.treeNodes = this.accessService.buildTreeTable(q));
```

This would be the right approach.

If you have any questions, feel free to ask !

Answer (score 0):

This is a normal way. And you make everything right. But if you want to structurize your code. And make it more readable you can youse different ways:

1. Use [forkJoin](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/forkJoin) method of `rxjs`

> Accepts an Array of `ObservableInput` or a dictionary Object of
>   `ObservableInput` and returns an `Observable` that emits either an array
>   of values in the exact same order as the passed array, or a dictionary
>   of values in the same shape as the passed dictionary.

```
private buildPermissionService() {
    return this.permissionService.build();
}

private buildTitlesWithMenus() {
    return this.accessService.buildTitlesWithMenus();
}

private buildMenuAndPermissions() {
    return forkJoin(
        this.buildPermissionService(),
        this.buildTitlesWithMenus()).subscribe(result => {
        this.Headers = result[0];
        this.treeNodes = this.accessService.buildTreeTable(result[1]);
    });
}
```

2. Use [switchMap](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/switchMap) method of `rxjs`

> Projects each source value to an Observable which is merged in the
>   output Observable, emitting values only from the most recently
>   projected Observable.

```
this.permissionService.build().pipe(
  tap(p => this.Headers = p),
  switchMap(p => this.accessService.buildTitlesWithMenus()),
).subscribe(q => this.treeNodes = this.accessService.buildTreeTable(q));
```

And more methods you can find in the documentation. For example, if you need not only get the result but and combine it you can use [zip](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/zip) or [combineAll](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/combineAll).